# Paving The Way Won't Complete

Tags: fallout-3

So I've been doing the Operation: Anchorage DLC for Fallout 3 and was on the quest Paving the Way.  I attacked the Chinese Listeing Post, cleared it out, checked every corner (pressing V everywhere for good measure) and as far as I can see all NPCs are dead.

However my strike team wouldn't let me complete the mission.  Sgt Montgomery just keeps saying 'attacking the listening post as ordered Sir...", so I got frustrated and used the following console command:

```
CompleteAllObjectives 020009c0
```

This is supposed to complete all the objectives for that quest, and in my Pipboy it says that is the case.   However the quest is still marked active, Sgt Montgomery still says the same thing, and I can't progress out of this DLC.

Has anybody experienced this or has any idea how I can end this particular quest so I can start the last part?

Comment: If you have an older save I think you'd best load that and try the quest again. I hope you have a save from not too long ago.

Comment: yes I keep save game files, however I don't want to necessarily just do that if I get back through that quest and encounter the same issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *Operation: Anchorage* DLC has plenty of [bugs](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Operation:_Anchorage_bugs), including the one you have mentioned.

You may be able to salvage the save by saving then reloading.  This appears to fix some of the issues in the DLC.

If this does not work you can use the following command:

`setstage <quest ID> <stage ID>`

Answer (score 3):

What helped for me was standing at the outpost balcony (while no enemy was there), and using the waiting utility (press <kbd>T</kbd>, wait 1 hour). After waiting, 2 enemies spawned there, after I killed them, the quest was marked complete.

Answer (score 1):

If waiting an hour on the balcony doesn't work then make sure you killed the Chinese technicians. This may help you finish the quest.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously been a bit but you just need to go back through the map a little, and then go back to the outpost and it should spawn more guys that finish the task when killed.

Answer (score 0):

If you go out of the door at the end of the listening post there is a bunker where 2 Chinese snipers are hanging out. After you've killed everyone, outside of the entrance, three soldiers will also spawn.